# HP ALM connexion

Tags: sql-server, hp-alm

I installed HP ALM tool,but when opening the app from the launcher,I have to fill this field to launch the tool:
[image]

I installed SQL-Server,but I can't connect even to the IP address defined in TCP properties with the browser:
[image]

[image]

This is the SQL server manager configuration:

[image]
[image]

any help please,I am working with windows 10 machine and I need to work with HP ALM tool.
Thanks

Comment: any help please :(

Comment: You can't use a web browser to connect directly to an SQL Server. SQL Servers speak an entirely different protocol (MS-TDS, Tabular Data Stream) than web browsers (HTTP, HTTPS).

Comment: I expect the ALM Client Launcher is expecting the URL for your HP ALM server, wherever you have installed that. It should look something similar to `http://YourALMServerNameOrIpAddress:ProbablyPort8080/qcbin`

Comment: thanks for your reply so I have to install HP ALM server??can you guide me please?because I followed many videos on youtube they did not mention any HP ALM Server

Comment: how can I fix HP ALM as server please.Thanks.